# How to auto size GridView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

How can I make my GridView autosize to the screen resolution. I looks good in the virtual device but not on my phone. I tried alot of settings but nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


            <GridView

             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:orientation="vertical"      
             android:id="@+id/gridview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:numColumns="3"
             android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
             android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"        
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

getView from ImageAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
    return imageView;
}
```

Virtual device:
[image: Virtual device]

Phone
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the gridview, problem is with imageview itself.

As you can see, your grid is actually occupying the screen and filling extra space with columnswidth. In your case, you have to place the image in center. To do this, give your imageview a parent such as linearlayout and align imageview to center in parent.

```
LinearLayout lLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
lLayout.addView(<your imageview>);
```

Use the above code in adapter getview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout lLayout;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    lLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
    lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams   (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    lLayout.addView(imageView);
    } else {
        lLayout= (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }


  ((ImageView)lLayout.getChildAt(0)).setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);

    return lLayout;
}
```

Comment: could you help me out with some code? Dont know where to add this code exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
```

It's 200dx not dp that why . 
So creat dimensions.xml in Values folder like

```
<resources>
 <dimen name="gridview">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

then

```
 int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
```